# using split() method in an arraylist object the code is incomplete

Tags: java

```js
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
        Scanner read = new Scanner(inputFile);
        File outputFile = new File("output.txt");
        PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
        if (!inputFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File does not exist!");
        }
        ArrayList<Event> myArray = new ArrayList<>();
        String commands="";
        while (read.hasNext()) {
         if(commands.matches("AddMovie")){
           addMovie(read);  
         }
            
            
            
            
        }

        print.flush();
        print.close();
        read.close();

    }
    
    //java netbeans
 public static Event addMovie(Scanner in){
    String m[]=new String[6];
     for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
         String name=in.next();
         Date sDate=new Date(in.next());
         Date eDate=new Date(in.next());
         double price=in.nextDouble();
         String city=in.next();
         String address=in.next();
         String language=in.next();
         String tAudience=in.next();
         double raiting=in.nextDouble();
         int tickets=in.nextInt();
     }
     
 return movie;}
```

well I am having a problem here so my program must read from a file these given data

AddMovie--The Upside, 6/3/2019, 6/6/2019, 50, Riyadh, Al Qasr Mall, English, Family, 4.5, 40, Comedy, Nicole Kidman, F, 1967

I have to store them in an ArrayList of object and I have to use non-word characters as a delimiter to split these data should I make a method and inside this method a 1-dimensional array and then use split() method?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Please share the code that you've tried with so far.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand you are on the right track. Given you read the data you have provided as one single string, you can use the *split(",")* method on it and store the result of that into an array of strings.

Comment: so i can use an array of string to split data and then store them in arrayList of object?

Comment: Well, the _split()_ method produces an array of strings, which could be then converted to an _ArrayList_ object.

Answer (score 0):

I think that splitting on 'non-word characters' would not be a good idea, as for example you would not want 4.5 to be split into 4 and 5.
I would probably split on ','.
If you were worried about efficiency, it would be a good idea to create a java.util.regex.Pattern object with (for e.g.)

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(",");
```

then whenever you wanted to use it, using:

```
pat.split(theString);
```